# Can I set the LANG variable from within sed?

Tags: sed

I wrote a script to replace certain expressions and remove others, but it failed in cleaning up special characters. Setting LANG=C solved that, but is it possible to set that environment variable from within sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is a `sed` script, you can just bump that part down and put it into a standard shell script.  e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

1 {
    x
    s/^$/          /
    s/^.*$/&&&&&&&&/
    x
}
```

into

```
#!/bin/sh

export LANG=C

/usr/bin/sed '
1 {
    x
    s/^$/          /
    s/^.*$/&&&&&&&&/
    x
}
' "$@"
```

(from an example in the `sed` `info` document.)

With the trailing `"$@"`, it should pass arguments and handle stdin the same way.

Comment: Use `"$@"`; the double quotes are crucial.  Without them, $@ is the same as $* and destroys spaces in file names (more accurately, it treats them as separators and splits the name into two or more pieces passed as separate arguments).  **Always** use `"$@"` (well, almost always; 'always' until you know why you don't need to in some special case - in the general case, you use `"$@"` and don't think twice about it).

Answer (score 2):

No, but you don't have to. You can set the envirinment variable before executing your sed command.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable so that it's active only for the single invocation of a command or script:

```
LANG=C sed ...
```

or

```
LANG=C sedscript
```